# Arithmetic operations in ASM Language

Tags: math, assembly, masm32, operations, q

I just need some help. I don't fully understand and I am fairly new to masm32 so if you could explain, that would be great!

```
MOV AX, 200
ADD AX, 300
MOV RESULT, AX
```

Will result be equal to 500? I tried adding 3 and 2 and using this to show output:

```
MOV DX, RESULT
ADD RESULT, '0'
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H
```

But the output is a candy cane character! Where is it wrong?

Now I assume subtraction will work the same as addition, so on to Multiplication we go.
This is what I did for multiplication

```
MOV AX, 30
MOV BX, 8
MUL BX
MOV RESULT, AX
```

Is RESULT's value equal to 240?.... 
I tried AX as 3 and BX as 2. The output is a spade. Can you point me to the right direction?

Now division.

```
MOV AX, 30
MOV BX, 12
DIV BX
MOV RESULT, AX
```

What holds the quotient? If what I read was correct, that would be AX, and DX holds the remainder...?

I have already done 8 bit arithmetic (using AL, BL, DL...) and I tried to apply it here, sadly, when the RESULT becomes greater than 128, it just outputs garbage. Someone suggested that I should declare my variables as 'RESULT dw ?' instead of 'RESULT db ?' and instead of AL BL registers I should use AX BX....  Now I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated! Sorry if these questions seem too trivial. Anyway, thanks in advance! :DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `MOV AX, 200`
>   `ADD AX, 300`
>   `MOV RESULT, AX`
>   Will result be equal to 500?

Yes.

---

> I tried adding 3 and 2 and using this to show output:
>   `MOV DX, RESULT`
>   `ADD RESULT, '0'`
>   `MOV AH, 02H`
>   `INT 21H`
>   But the output is a candy cane character! Where is it wrong?

You're adding `'0'` to `RESULT` *after* moving `RESULT` to `DX`. You should probably add `'0'` to `DL` instead of to `RESULT`.

---

> Now division.
>   `MOV AX, 30`
>   `MOV BX, 12`
>   `DIV BX`
>   `MOV RESULT, AX`
>   What holds the quotient? If what I read was correct, that would be AX, and DX holds the remainder...?

`DIV BX` divides the 32-bit value `DX:AX` by `BX`, so you should clear `DX` before the division. The quotient will end up in `AX` and the remainder in `DX`.

---

> Someone suggested that I should declare my variables as `RESULT dw ?`

If you're going to move 16-bit values to/from the variable (e.g. `MOV RESULT,AX`) then you should make the variable (at least) 16 bits.